# How i can play audio from url and downloading it in cache at the same time?

Tags: android, kotlin, audio, exoplayer

I want to use exoplayer for this task and i need to start playing audio from url and cache it at the same time. When URL will dead i need to play audio from cache. URL is alive during for 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ExoPlayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer), it should handle streaming on its own.

```
val mediaSource = extractMediaSourceFromUri(Uri.parse("asset:///heart_attack.mp3"))
        val exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
            baseContext, DefaultRenderersFactory(baseContext)
            , DefaultTrackSelector(),
            DefaultLoadControl()
        )
        exoPlayer.apply {
            // AudioAttributes here from exoplayer package !!!
            val attr = AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(C.USAGE_MEDIA)
                .setContentType(C.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .build()
            // In 2.9.X you don't need to manually handle audio focus :D
            setAudioAttributes(attr, true)
            prepare(mediaSource)
            // THAT IS ALL YOU NEED 
            playWhenReady = true
        }
```